# Porque este código de python no se me ejecuta?

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenas Noches a todos antes que nada.
Actualmente ando aprendiendo a programar en el lenguaje **Python** y ando con el tema de los GUI, hice el siguiente código con la intencion de probar las funcionalidades de la libreria **tkinter**:

```py
from tkinter import *
raiz=Tk()
raiz.geometry("800x800")
raiz.title("Ventana de prueba")
raiz.config(bg="red")
raiz.mainloop()
```

Pero por algun motivo solo se me ejecuta en la consola de windows, no importa en que IDE o editor de texto lo intento ejecutar no logro que funcione, alguien podria explicarme de manera clara porque ocurre esto?

Muchas gracias y feliz día a todos

Comment: Te lanza algún tipo de error? He copiado tu código y me funciona correctamente en CentOS, puedes compartir además la forma en la que lo estas ejecutando.

Comment: El código es correcto (la siempre mala costumbre de `from tkinter import *`, pero correcto), la prueba es que tu mismo confirmas que ejecutado en la consola funciona sin problemas. El problema seguramente está en cómo lo ejecutas no en el el código, en cómo tienes configurados los ides o el intérprete que usan. Es importante que como comenta allexiusw agregues si al ejecutar en los IDES te da algún error, así como que expliques que IDES has probado y cómo están configurados para usar Python.

Comment: en la consola de python me dice que la sintaxis es invalida, lo único que he notado es que esa versión es la 3.8.3 y en la de windows es la 3.7.7     en sublime text por ejemplo con la extensión sublimeREPL se me ejecuta la ventana pero no lee los cambios con el color el titulo o el tamaño de la ventana

Comment: Puedes agregar el error tal cual te lo da la terminal o IDE al la pregunta por favor?